# Extracting large sets of data from a data frame pyspark

Tags: neo4j, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook, bigdata

I've been recently working with pyspark on Jupyter notebook. I'm trying to read data from  parquet files in order to construct a graph in Neo4J with these data. I can successfully load data from HDFS into the data frames.

When data size is limited everything works fine, I'm able to extract a python list using the collect() method then loop over it. When data size increases, obviously I get a "java heap size" error (the data frame contains over 13 million and couple hundred thousands lines distributed over five columns).

I have tried to use the foreach(f) but I get "tuple index out of range".
When I use df.select('columnName').show(), I'm able to view the data; but the thing is that I need to extract the values in order to construct the graph using a Neo4j session (session.run('Cypher query')

My question is: Is there any way to loop over the lines (and therefore extract data from the rows) of a data frame when I have an important amount of data?

P.S: I am using these librairies: findspark, pyspark, neo4j.v1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that there were no answers. Well I am publishing how I solved things in case someone in the future had the same problem. The exact same code worked on a python 2 kernel but not on a python 3. 
I had to install an older version of jupyter that supported pyhton 2.7 and things worked out perfectly (In case you work on a server on which you have full permissions and internet connexion, you might simply install a new kernel in addition to the first one).
Instead of using the collect(), I used foreachPartition() and it worked out perfectly.